# How are binaries loaded in the default Arduino bootloader through USB?

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I got a desktop program that interfaces with an Arduino.

I need to be sure the correct program, either Processing or pre-compiled AVR binary is loaded as part of my handshake routine with the Arduino.

What are the steps for initializing the download/new program loading procedure on the Arduino Uno R3 with default bootloader?

I want to recreate the upload command found in the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Arduino IDE do this:

1. Plug the Uno into your computer.
2. File > Preferences > Show verbose output during: > compilation(uncheck), upload (check) > OK
3. Select the correct board from the Tools > Board menu
4. Select the correct port from the Tools > Port menu
5. Sketch > Upload
6. After the upload completes resize the black console window at the bottom of the Arduino IDE window and scroll up to the top. You will see the exact AVRDUDE command that was used to upload to the Arduino.

You can copy and adapt that command as needed for use with your program.

Comment: Okay, this is what I did, but somehow this doesn't answer the original question :-)

Comment: You said "I want to recreate the upload command found in the IDE". I showed you how to do that. So what part of the question still needs to be answered?

Comment: The actual sequence that the exe implements.

Comment: By exe do you mean the Arduino IDE or AVRDUDE?